# Wrapping a single variable callback function with more variables javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, callback, cordova, wrapper

Okay I've been working on this for a few days and I haven't found any examples that have helped for this instance. This seems like a very common scenerio so maybe I am just not looking in the right spot, or maybe the solution is more complicated than I want it to be.

I have a pre-built function, transaction, that takes the callback function queryDB.

```
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

By design queryDB will have a "tx" or database transaction object to make the SQL call.

```
function queryDB(tx){
   alert("transact");
   tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Sound", [], rqDB, errorCB);
}
```

Now I want to pass some extra variables to queryDB, in particular sqlCmd and a results callback function. I have tried a number of ways of wrapping queryDB, the one I like the most looks like this:

```
db.transaction({
    onQueryDB: function(tx) {
        queryDB(tx,sqlCmd,cb);
    }
}, errorCB, successCB);
```

But this does not call my queryDB function. This seems like something that should be simple and common in javascript. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an object instead of a function! Use this instead:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    queryDB(tx,sqlCmd,cb);
}, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: Wow, thankyou that did the trick. And... it was simpler than what I was thinking, Awesome!

I am sure I tried this before, ...something else must have been broken at the time, anyway, thanks a billion.